# How to block outgoing traffic of the mac address of one of the server's own NIC with ip tables?

Tags: debian, iptables, mac, nic, address

i have a server with 5 nics connected to a switch, and running GNS3 (cisco router emulator).

I need to block, in the server, the packets originated by the nics at layer 2 level (the nics are not configured with ip) so i have to block with ip tables, the outgoing traffic in every nic with its own mac address as source.

i have tried some commands like this but it does not work iptables -I "CHAIN-NAME" -m mac --mac-source "MAC-ADDRESS" -j "ACTION"

I'm using DEBIAN 7

Comment: What does "not work" mean, it gave you errors, or just didn't stop the traffic? Also why are you trying to stop layer 2 traffic with a layer 3 firewall?

Answer (score 2):

You need to look into [ebtables](http://ebtables.sourceforge.net/), as iptables is a layer 3 firewall/filter.